# Use different value of input field than it is showing in React Form

Tags: reactjs, input, react-final-form

I have a form in react, and I want the input field to show "No Limit" as default value if no other value specified, or the customer input otherwise. but If no value specified, I need the value to be -1 (for other part of the code).

My code right now lokks like this:

```
import { Field, Form } from "react-final-form";


const RecordingForm = (props: Props) => {
  const onSubmit = (values: any) => {
  //some code here...
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        initialValues={{ totaltime_maximum: -1,}}
        render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

            <Field name="totaltime_maximum">
              {({ input, meta }) => (
                <div>
                  <label>Maximum duration (seconds):</label>
                  <input {...input} type="number" placeholder="No Limit" />
                  {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
                </div>
              )}
            </Field>

          </form>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default RecordingForm;
```

But, the result of this code is this input box:

[image: my input box]

And I want it to look like this:

[image: the wanted input box]

and the value (to my using in the code) to be -1.

how can I do that?

Comment: i guess you need a custom component with props like realValue and displayedValue

Comment: Looks like with react-final-form initialValues will always override the placeholder, which makes sense. One option is to write the logic in onSubmit to handle an empty value for totaltime_maximum and don't give it an initial value

Comment: react-final-form initialValues doesn't overide the placeholde. when earasing the -1 in the input box, you see the "No Limit" placeholder below.